# Help adding network folder in Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, samba

I have a Windows shared folder that I can mount and access in Kubuntu, using Smb4K. The problem is adding it through the Network Folder Wizard of Dolphin. I chose the type called "Microsoft Windows network drive" and configured it as pasted below, but it says

```
Unable to connect to server
```

Or maybe there is another easy, convenient way to mount the share? The shared folder is in a VM so I don't want it to automount at login; that would fail, I think, because the VM won't be launched yet.

[image]

Comment: I don't know about this wizard, but I guess Server should be `SHMUEL-WIN7`, and folder `/Users/Shmuel/Dropbox`

Comment: That didn't work either, but see my edit of the OP -- I am open to alternative methods to mount the share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just create what everyone else calls a Bookmark.

Right click an empty space on the left side panel of dolphin and select **Add Entry**

Give the network path to the shared resource: **smb://server/share**

Like this:

[image]

Then it will show up under Network on the side panel:

[image]